# Idiomatic way to convert from a scanner to a io.Reader

Tags: go, io

I recently ran into this issue of how to read from a CSV file, apply some transformation to every line and write to a HTTP request.

The problem I was faced with was how to convert from a line-by-line reader which returns an arbitrary number of bytes (like a Scanner) to a byte reader, which returns a fixed amount of bytes at every call to Read().

The best solution I came up with is to build a custom io.Reader that would read from the Scanner and buffer bytes locally if they wouldn't fit. Then the buffered bytes would be returned on the next call to Read().

This is what I came up with:
https://gist.github.com/paulsc/6a0bf30a2a8d898f7a8086aedf6af1e1

Intuitively, this feels like the wrong solution, because the code seems like a fairly low-level solution that might already be in the standard library.

Is there a better way, more idiomatic to do this with standard go components ?

Comment: The `bufio.Scanner` uses an `io.Reader` underneath, but gives no way to access it from outside. Since `bufio.NewScanner` method requires an `io.Reader`, you'd only need to use the `io.Reader` you've created beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method is using `io.Pipe`.

```
func ScannerToReader(scanner *bufio.Scanner) io.Reader {
    reader, writer := io.Pipe()


    go func() {
        defer writer.Close()
        for scanner.Scan() {
            writer.Write(scanner.Bytes())
        }
    }()

    return reader
}
```

Comment: This eats the newlines though. fmt.Fprintln preserves them.

Comment: Thanks. One thing I still don't understand though. How can I apply this to a call to http.NewRequest(method, url string, body io.Reader) ? It seems like with NewRequest the code is "Reader-driven" as in, the http request will do the job of making Read() calls. If I use a pipe, my code becomes "Writer-driven" where something needs to trigger the write, in your example the go() function above.

If I understand correctly, if I call NewRequest() first it will block until there's something to read, or... wait I think the coin just dropped. Is that what the goroutine is for ? Not familar with it.

Comment: Yes the goroutine is to disallow it from blocking while converting

Comment: Ok I just tried it out. I definitely learned something but I still have a problem. 

Using this goroutine method, my http request writes data to the server in chunks, line-by-line. If I look at the network traffic using wireshark, I can see one packet going out per line instead of a big packet with all the data at once. This seems like it will affect performance. 

Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: So I ended up taking your code, and wrapping it in [another reader that forces full buffer reads](https://gist.github.com/paulsc/ca9e5437cd784cf81b2b18c1f0321ea7). This works, but again feels hacky. I thought the bufio.Reader would've worked here, but it still passed on the reads line-by-line, instead of filling the 32k bytes buffer. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @paulsc what I'm still not understanding is what you want to achieve on a higher level

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm reading a CSV of time-series data from disk, and posting to InfluxDB which has an HTTP api. So I'm reformating the CSV on the fly for the API, and want to write chunks of 5k lines for best performance. I have a Scanner that outputs lines of DB-compatible stuff. I need to somehow hook that to my http Request, which wants an io.Reader. If I use your suggestion, the http request ends up reading one line at a time and sending one line per network packet. That's why I'm trying to force full buffer reads so that multiple lines get sent at once. My solution seems hacky though.

Comment: Did you consider a streaming option on the network level ? Like HTTP/2 or sockets

Comment: Well it's using chunked transfer encoding, which is streaming. Also I'm depending on my DB, so can't change the network protocol. My question was more around if there's an idomatic way to force full-buffer reads. I was just curious. Anyhow the current solution is already miles better than before.